# Wrapping objective-C code in @try-catch block

Tags: objective-c

Is something wrong if I wrap every method code in

```
@try {
}
catch(NSException e) {}
```

I am new developer. So please help. I wrap my code in try-catch block to remove application crash possibilities.

Comment: If you application is raising exceptions you're doing something wrong.

Comment: Yes, something would be terribly wrong if you used `try/catch` in every method. I have a project with 250,000 lines of code and I use `try/catch` two times.

Comment: To be blunt;   exceptions in Objective-C are **only used to indicate non-recoverable errors**.  They should never be used for user recoverable or other recoverable errors.

Comment: You should accept Wain's answer.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, it's a bad idea.

When your app throws an exception it means something is seriously wrong, if you just catch and hide that whatever was wrong is still wrong, you haven't fixed it, so you're probably going to get another exception again soon. Some exceptions can't be handled anyway. So, just catching and hiding exceptions will probably still result in an app that doesn't work.

So, you should have very few try/catch blocks, because exceptions aren't used for navigation in obj-c.